# Use of Transactional annotation in Spring data with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, transactional

I'm using Spring data and Hibernate to manage my database. I have for example repository class like this:

```
public interface NotificationHasUserRepository extends JpaRepository<NotificationHasUser, NotificationHasUserKeys> {

    List<NotificationHasUser> findByPkUserAndIsReadFalse(User user);

    @Modifying  
    @Query("UPDATE NotificationHasUser u SET u.isRead=true WHERE u.pk.user = ?1")
    void setNotificationsAsRead(User user);

    void deleteByPkUserAndPkNotification(User user, Notification notification);

    List<NotificationHasUser> findByPkUser(User user);

    @Query("select count(u)>0 from NotificationHasUser u WHERE u.pk.notification = ?1")
    boolean existsByPkNotification(Notification notification);
}
```

I inject this class in my service class:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class NotificationHasUserServicesImpl implements NotificationHasUserServices {

    @Resource
    private NotificationHasUserRepository notificationHasUserRepository;

    @Override
    public NotificationHasUser create(NotificationHasUser notificationHasUser) {
        return notificationHasUserRepository.save(notificationHasUser);
    }

    @Override
    public NotificationHasUser findById(NotificationHasUserKeys id) {
        return notificationHasUserRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean exists(NotificationHasUserKeys id) {
        return notificationHasUserRepository.exists(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<NotificationHasUser> findByPkUserAndIsReadFalse(User user) {
        return notificationHasUserRepository.findByPkUserAndIsReadFalse(user);  
    }

    @Override
    public void setNotificationsAsRead(User user) {
        notificationHasUserRepository.setNotificationsAsRead(user); 
    }

    @Override
    public List<NotificationHasUser> getNotifications(User user) {
        return notificationHasUserRepository.findByPkUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteSelectedNotification(User user, Notification notification) {
        notificationHasUserRepository.deleteByPkUserAndPkNotification(user, notification);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean existsByPkNotification(Notification notification) {
        return notificationHasUserRepository.existsByPkNotification(notification);
    }
}
```

I'm using @Transaction on the service class but I receive exception when I call delete or update query

```
.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

If I add @Transcational on each method in repository class all work fine, is it not possible to add at service level?Thanks
This is my spring configuration:

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "com.*" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class, SpringMvcInitializer.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.repository")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements AsyncConfigurer{
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    @Autowired
    private MyAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler myAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler;

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    //  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";


    /**
     * This and the next methods are used to avoid exception while jackson mapping the entity, so fields are setted with null value
     * unless use Hibernate.initialize
     * @return
     */
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter(){
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //Registering Hibernate4Module to support lazy objects
        mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());

        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        return messageConverter;

    }
    /**
     * Used for spring security
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect() {
        SpringSecurityDialect dialect = new SpringSecurityDialect();
        return dialect;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        //Here we add our custom-configured HttpMessageConverter
        converters.add(jacksonMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        //      properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
        properties.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans",true);
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        ds.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        ds.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        ds.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver TemplateResolver(){
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        return resolver;
        /*ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        return resolver;*/
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(TemplateResolver());
        templateEngine.addDialect(springSecurityDialect());
        return templateEngine;
    }


    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setViewNames(new String[]{"*", "js/*", "template/*"});
        return resolver;
    }

    /**
     * Register multipartResolver for file upload
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        return resolver;    
    }

    /**
     * Allow use of bootstrap
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

    /**
     * Allow use of JPA
     */
    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.
                getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    /**
     * Async exception configuration 
     */
    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(10);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return myAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your Spring application context configuration

Comment: I've added my Spring configuration